# jqGrid get "th" and "thead" using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

How can I get `theader` on a jqGrid using jQuery?

Answer (score 16):

My short answer is: instead of selecting of the DOM elements which corresponds `<th>` elements which you are looking for you should use

```
$("#list")[0].grid.headers
```

It returns the array of this DOM elements, corresponds the `<th>`. The long description of my answer follows.

I understand the reason of your question. If you have for example defined the base part of jqGrid as

```html
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

then `$("#list")` gives you `<table>` with only the **"data"** part of the grid **without headers**. The main "data" part of the table will be placed inside some divs. Other elements of jqGrid will be placed in the divs as a tables. The structure of jqGrid (not full) will looks like following:

```
div.ui-jqgrid#gbox_list
  div.ui-jqgrid-view#gview_list
    div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar              - caption
    div.ui-userdata#t_list              - optional top toolbar
    div.ui-jqgrid-toppager#list_toppager - optional top pager
    div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv                  - all grid headers
      div.ui-jqgrid-hbox                - (div.ui-jqgrid-hbox-rtl) if direction:"rtl"
        table.ui-jqgrid-htable
          thead
            tr.ui-jqgrid-labels         - row with column headers (labels)
              th#list_rn                - optional column header with row numbers
              th#list_Col1              - column header for the column name:"Col1"
              ...
              th#list_level             - optional column header for some other
                                          special columns in case of usage TreeGrid
                                          the hidden columns of TreeGrid are: level,
                                          parent, isLeaf, expanded, loaded, icon
            tr.ui-search-toolbar        - row for toolbar searching
              th
              th
              ...
    div.frozen-div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv       - optional frozen headers
        table.ui-jqgrid-htable          - table with frozen columns headers only
          ...
    div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv                  - div with the main grid data
      div
        table#list                      - table with the main grid data
    div.frozen-bdiv.ui-jqgrid-bdiv      - optional div with the main grid data
      div
        table#list_frozen               - table with the main grid data
    div.ui-userdata#tb_list             - optional bottom toolbar
  div.ui-jqgrid-resize-mark#rs_mlist
  div.ui-jqgrid-pager#pager             - the div with the pager
```

(here in the table I used `rownumbers: true`, so there are `th#list_rn`, the first column has the name 'Col1', so there are `th#list_Col1` and so on)

You can see, that the header table `table.ui-jqgrid-htable` can has two child `<tr>` subelements: one `tr.ui-jqgrid-labels` for the column headers and one `tr.ui-search-toolbar` for the `filterToolbar`.

My suggestion for you don't use this relatively complex hierarchy, but use another short hidden way existing in jqGrid. The code

```js
var gridDom = $("#list")[0];
```

get you DOM element of the table element. This element has some important extension which are made by jqGrid. This are `gridDom.p` which contain all parameters of jqGrid. Another important extension is `gridDom.grid` with important properties `bDiv`, `cDiv`, `hDiv`, `fbDiv`, `fhDiv`, `uDiv` and also `cols`, `footers`, `topDiv` and `headers`. I suggest you to use `gridDom.grid.headers` array as the best way to receive a list of `<th>` elements from the grid column headers (from the correct `<tr>` row).

Answer (score 0):

If a `thead` and `th` exists on the DOM, it can be selected. Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery("thead", "#mygrid")
```