# jqGrid - how to change title based on colModel sortable property

Tags: jqgrid

When the mouse hovers over each column I'd like the **tooltip** to indicate whether that column is sortable. 
I am able to change the **title** attribute with something like this:

```
$("#List .ui-th-column").each(function(i) { 
    var isSortable = i % 2;
    $(this).attr('title', isSortable ? "Not Sortable" : "Click header to sort."); 
});
```

I'd like to replace the demo expression *'i % 2'* with a check of the **colMode's sortable** property, but I can't figure out how to get the value of the colModel's sortable property.

```
colModel: [ { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 100, sortable: true  },
            { name: 'Note', index: 'Note', width: 200, sortable: false } ]
```

I've tried .getGridParam and .getColProp but I don't think the syntax I'm using is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the `sortable` property like any other property from the column definition you can do about following:

```
var grid=$("#list");
var propsName = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','Name');
var propsNote = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','Note');
alert("'Name' has sortable="+propsName.sortable+
      "\n'Note' has sortable="+propsNote.sortable);
```

To set tooltip on the column header you can do following

```
var setTooltipsOnColumnHeader = function (grid, iColumn, text) {
    var thd = $("thead:first", grid.hdiv)[0];
    $("tr th:eq(" + iColumn + ")", thd).attr("title", text);
};
var grid=$("#list");
setTooltipsOnColumnHeader(grid,2,"Bla Bla!");
```

Here we identify the column by index of visible columns.

You can easy rewrite the code examples for your purpose.

Comment: @Greg: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: the var propsName = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','Name'); gives me the boolean i need for the isSortable - thanks. Is there a way for me to use the variable i in the .each(function(i) to replace the column name so i don't have to type 'Name', 'Description' etc?

Comment: @Greg: the var propsName = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','Name'); gives **an object** having boolean property `sortable` if it is defined in the `colModel``. Look at the example http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/isSortable.htm. Of cause you can make a loop through all columns, but the usage of `$("#List .ui-th-column")` seems me wrong because columns are not a part of `$("#List")`. jqGrid some parent divs over the main table element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462071/jqgrid-get-th-and-thead-using-jquery/3463002#3463002 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely. thanks for all the help Oleg.

```
$("#gbox_List .ui-th-column").each(function(i) {
    var col = grid.getGridParam('colModel'); 
    var isSortable = grid.jqGrid("getColProp", col[i].name).sortable;
    $(this).attr('title', isSortable ? "Click header to sort by column." : "Not Sortable"); 
});
```

You were right about the **$(#List** not being in the correct place on the DOM, it should have been **#gbox_List** - the additional info made that clear.

I had to use .ui-th-**column** rather than .ui-th-**labels** for the .each to loop through each column.

I was able to avoid hard coding the column name by using the **grid.getGridParam('colModel')** to return an array and then grabbing the **.name** property off of that for each column.

This solution is nice because I have ~20 grids, each with lots of unsortable columns and having to have a different line for each unsortable column would have been messy. Now I can take advantage of the sortable property setting in the colModel.