# jqgrid get header and caption height size

Tags: jqgrid

How can i get the height size of :
header title bar,
and the size of the bar above the header , where the caption is.

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462071/jqgrid-get-th-and-thead-using-jquery/3463002#3463002) I described the anotomy of jqGrid elements. Small modification of In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806279/jqgrid-tooltip-for-header-cells-only) to you will give

```
var mygrid = $("#list");
var header_height=$("thead:first tr.ui-jqgrid-labels", mygrid[0].grid.hDiv).height();
```

You can also use [$.outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) if it is more suitable for you as [$.height](http://api.jquery.com/height/). In the same way the caption height can be calculated with

```
var caption_height=$("div#gview_"+mygrid[0].id+" > div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar").height();
```