# Does jqgrid support tooltips on header cells (and grouped header cells)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, tooltip

I am using jqgrid and I want to have a tooltip that is a different value for each column heading (i want to put in the description in to a tooltip) for each column name.  In my case I am using the treegrid but my question applies to both the treegrid and the regular jqgrid.

Is this possible? Again, I am looknig to do this for every column header (both regular and grouped header cols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806615/315935) gives the answer on your question too.

If you prefer to use more direct way as described in the answer you can just use the fact that all `<th>` elements of the column headers has ids which are constructed from the id of the grid, like "list" and the value of the `name` property of the column, like "tax", and the underscore ("_") between. So in the described above example the id of the column will be "list_tax". So you can set the tooltip just by setting of the `title` attribute on the corresponding `<th>` element:

```
$("#list_tax").attr("title", "my tooltip");
```

Comment: @leora: The grouping header is just in the first `<td>` of the `<tr>` elements having `"jqgroup"` class. You can additionally use `groupingView.sortnames[0]` to have the list of all groups.

Answer (score 0):

To add tooltip just call this methode on loadcomplete:

```
addToolTipForColumnheader('YourGridID');

function addToolTipForColumnheader(gridID){
    var columnNameList=$('#'+gridID)[0].p.colNames;
    for (var i = 0; i < columnNameList.length; i++){
        var columnName=$('#'+gridID)[0].p.colModel[i].name;
        $('#'+gridID+'_'+columnName).attr("title", $('#'+gridID)[0].p.colNames[i]);
    }
}
```