# Triggering resize of jqGrid after user shows/hides columns

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

In jqGrid, after a users chooses to remove a column(s), a grid's width becomes smaller.  Therefore, I think it would be appropriate to trigger a resize at this point using `$("#myGrid").trigger("resize")`. However, **to what jqGrid event should I attach this?**

I tried triggering a resize manually on the Firebug Console after using the Column Chooser and it worked well.

I also tried the recommendations in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515899/jqgrid-with-columnchooser-how-to-prevent-autoresize-after-columns-choice) but without any results.

Comment: Does anyone know how to handle this in angular?  It seems that this is not a valid option, when attempting to resize

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my own problem:

```
     $("#myGrid").jqGrid("columnChooser", {
        done: function() {
          $("#myGrid").trigger("resize");
        }
      });
```

Comment: Works fine with jqGrid version 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

If you use the last version of jqGrid (currently it is 4.1.1) the bug fixes which I described before are already included in the main code of jqGrid. So how you can see from [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser1.htm) all seems to work correct without doing anything.