# JQGrid: Resize Grid Width After Column Resized

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, resize

I would like to resize the width of the grid after a column is resized (so the width of the grid will match the sum of the widths of the columns, including the new width of the resized column).  This should prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing as well.

This is sort of similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550507/triggering-resize-of-jqgrid-after-user-shows-hides-columns), where in addition to the grid resizing after hiding/showing columns, I would like it to resize when expanding/shrinking columns:

If you look at the [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser1.htm) in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550507/triggering-resize-of-jqgrid-after-user-shows-hides-columns) provided by @Oleg, you can see that the grid does not resize upon the resize of a column.

There is a `resizeStop` event I could maybe use, and then use the method `setGridWidth` to set the grid to the width of the sum of the widths of the columns.  I'm not sure how to sum the widths of the columns though...Maybe there is something built into JQGrid that I could use to do this easily?

Thank you so much for any advice!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I personally find the question very good. I make many suggestions how to improve the algorithm of calculation of the grid width. Twice I included the behavior like you want in my suggestions, but Tony (the developer of jqGrid) removed the part of the changes.

To implement your requirements in the current version of jqGrid is very easy, but the code uses some internal grid structures. So you should verify whether the same trick will work in the next versions too. The code of the `resizeStop` callback can be the following:

```
resizeStop: function () {
    $(this.bDiv).find('>div:first>table.ui-jqgrid-btable:first')
                .jqGrid('setGridWidth', this.newWidth);
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooserAndResizing.htm) shows live how it works.

The complexity of the common solution for the jqGrid is higher because one needs sometimes to *hold* specified width of the grid. My point of view here is the following: if the user specify the `width` option *during the grid initialization (creating)* then he want to *hold* the width. On the other side if no `width` option are specified during creating of the grid one wish (like you as wish) the calculation of the total width of the grid based on the sum of the widths of all columns. In the case if some column width will be changed, the grid width should be adjusted (recalculated) too. The problem is only that the original empty `width` option will be *overwritten* during the grid creating. My suggestion would be to save the *original* value of `width` option in the `widthOrg` option during the grid creating. So one will be able to test the *original* value of `width` option and to choose the best behavior of the grid resizing after the column resizing.

**UPDATED**: After some discussion with you in comments and debugging of jqGrid code I hope that I found the solution which works correctly independent from the value of `shrinkToFit` parameter. The solution consists from changing the code of `resizeStop` to the following

```
resizeStop: function () {
    var $grid = $(this.bDiv).find('>div:first>table.ui-jqgrid-btable:first'),
        shrinkToFit = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'shrinkToFit');

    $grid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', this.newWidth, shrinkToFit);
}
```

and changing of two lines of internal `showHideCol` method of jqGrid. It's first changing of [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L2974)

```
cw = this.widthOrg? this.widthOrg: parseInt(this.width,10);
```

to

```
cw = this.widthOrg && $t.p.shrinkToFit ? this.widthOrg: parseInt(this.width,10);
```

and changing of [another line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L2981)

```
$($t).jqGrid("setGridWidth",$t.p.shrinkToFit === true ? $t.p.tblwidth : $t.p.width );
```

to

```
$($t).jqGrid("setGridWidth", $t.p.tblwidth);
```

You can get modified version of jqGrid [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-shrinkToFit.js). [The first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooserAndResizing1.htm) uses the code with `shrinkToFit: true` and [the second demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooserAndResizing2.htm) uses the same code, but without the option `shrinkToFit: true`.

I though in the next day how to make the fix working also in case of the usage fixed `width` option of jqGrid at the creating time and will post my suggestion to the trirand forum.

If you want uses minimized version of jqGrid you can either minimize it yourself or use the *original* jqGrid minimized version and overwrite only the `showHideCol` method with respect of `$.jgrid.extend`. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooserAndResizing1_.htm).

**UPDATED**: After changes of the value of `this` in later versions of jqGrid one should change the above code of `resizeStop` callback to about the following:

```
resizeStop: function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        shrinkToFit = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "shrinkToFit");

    $self.jqGrid("setGridWidth", this.grid.newWidth, shrinkToFit);
}
```

Comment: Oleg -  Thank you so much for your reply!!!  This works perfectly.  I understand your point as well.  I notice that when one column is resized, all other columns are resized proportionally.  To be able to resize a column without resizing the other columns, I found that 'shrinkToFit' needs to be set to false.  This, however, breaks the grid shrinking/expanding when removing/adding columns.  Soooo, I can override the 'done' option of the column chooser, but I'm not sure how to calculate the grid width there.

Comment: @icats: Do you mean optional second paremeter `shrink` of `setGridWidth` or the `shrinkToFit` option of jqGrid? Could you describe more exactly which settings you jqGrid has (especially the values of `shrinkToFit` and `forceFit` which you use). Could you additionally describe *exactly* which behavior you want to have in the grid after 1) one column will be resized by the user (the width on the column will be reduced or increased) 2) one column will be hidden or shown by the column chooser.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for my terrible description!  My grid options were virtually the same as yours (default `shrinkToFit`, `forceFit`, etc as I did not define them).  But, I added `shrinkToFit: false` in order for column resizing to not expand/shrink other columns proportionally.  Adding `shrinkToFit: false` broke the grid automatically resizing after adding/removing columns.

Comment: Basically, I would just like the grid to be the size of the sum of the column widths at all times.  So, adding columns or expanding columns should increase the grid width, and removing columns or shrinking columns should decrease the grid width.  Also, the initial width of the grid should just be the sum of the widths of the visible columns (with the column widths I defined in the colModel).  Thank you so much for your responses!

Comment: Oh, and I would like the expanding/shrinking of columns to not affect the widths of the other columns :)

Comment: ...`done: function(perm) { (perm) { this.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true); var gridWidth = ???; this.jqGrid("setGridWidth",gridWidth);} }` - I suspect the `done` option code on the column chooser would look something like this in order to fix the "bug" where when the grid option `shrinkToFit` is set to `false`, the grid does not shrink/expand when columns are removed/added. I'm just not sure how to perform the equivalent of the code you have in `resizeStop` here. I'll keep digging!

Comment: in the 'done' option of the column chooser, I added the following code: `this.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true); var gridWidth = $(this)[0].clientWidth; this.jqGrid('setGridWidth', gridWidth);`  I'm not sure if using `$(this)[0].clientWidth` to find the sum of the widths of the columns is the best approach (is this cross-browser compatible/upgrade safe?), but, this does fix the issue where when setting grid option `shrinkToFit = false` the width of the grid does not resize when adding/removing columns (with my code added in `done` the grid will shrink/expand when column was removed/added)

Comment: @icats: Try to increase the size of some column in your solution (resize it) and then hide the resized column with respect of the `columnChooser`. Do you have unchanged size of all other columns? I think currently that there are some bugs in resizing of jqGrid in case of `shrinkToFit: false`. So one should first fix the bugs and then the solution will be very easy. I will try to examine the problem later.

Comment: After resizing & then hiding the resized column, the size of all other columns remains unchanged (which is what I desire), and the grid shrinks to the width of the remaining columns.  However, I am noticing two bugs when resizing another column after the above steps: the little drag gray line indicator is off the same amount I shrunk the column I removed (see http://i.imgur.com/vgxZS.jpg). And, sometimes the code you gave above to execute on `resizeStop` will calculate the grid width to be too small (by the size I shrunk the column I removed), & the horizontal scroll bars show.

Comment: again, thank you so much for your help!  That was a good bug to find with my solution that I did not think about :)

Comment: @icats: You are welcome! I took a look in the code of jqGrid and made two small fixes. Could you look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooserAndResizing1.htm) which uses [the fixed code](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-shrinkToFit.js) and `shrinkToFit: false` [almost the same demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooserAndResizing2.htm), but without `shrinkToFit: false` and confirm that all works correctly?

Comment: I tried the things I did to cause the 'bugs' I mentioned above (and played around with it for a while performing various resizing/adding/dropping columns) and both grids function as I would expect them to!!  The first demo with the `shrinkToFit: false` behaves in exactly the same manner I was looking for!  Thank you so much!  Would you recommend minimizing this fixed code and using it directly?  Or, can you think of a good way for me to make it easy for future devs of my application to upgrade JQGrid and maintain this functionality (I will leave them plenty of notes:))?

Comment: @icats: I updated my answer and I hope that I answered on all your questions.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly!  I took your suggestion of using the original JQGrid minimized code and overwrite only the `showHideCol` method with respect of `$.jgrid.extend`.  Thank you so much for your help (very very much)!!!!

Comment: @icats: You are welcome! It's a pleasure to answer on good questions.

Answer (score 0):

I make a function

```
var grid_setAutoWidth = function() {

    var columnas = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');

    var anchoTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; columnas[i]; i++) {
        anchoTotal += columnas[i].width;
    }

    anchoTotal += 50;
    $(this).jqGrid('setGridWidth', anchoTotal);

};
```

... and then, in the grid params

```
shrinkToFit: false,
loadComplete: grid_setAutoWidth,
resizeStop: grid_setAutoWidth,
```

I think that is the easyest way