# Show scrollbar with jqGrid, when grid initially wider than page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in various places throughout a web app.  I want to use specified column widths (which I don't want to be changed to avoid wrapping/text cut off) and if the total of the column widths for a particular grid goes over the page width I want a scroll bar to appear on the grid, not on the page.  Is this possible with jqGrid options, or would some extra javascript be required as I haven't been able to get this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the width of the grid by setting it's width option (also remember you need to set `shrinkToFit: false` in your options), for example:

```
$('#gridId').jqGrid({
    ...
    shrinkToFit: false,
    width: $(document).width()
});
```

This can also be changed dynamically (for example on page resize) with `setGridWidth` method:

```
$('#gridId').jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(document).width())
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the setGridWidth and that did the trick...after I amended the wrapper that we use to create grids - it didn't enable setting shrinkToFit to false!

Comment: This doesn't present a horizontal scrollbar though, it just seems to do overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand you corrects: there are many opinions what is the best way to set the width of the grid.

In general you should use `shrinkToFit: false` and not use and `width` option of jqGrid if you want to have exact widths of columns like you specified in `colModel`. You can use [fixed: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) property for some columns if you don't want that the user be able to change the column width with respect of drop&drag of the partition between of the column header.

Additionally I recommend you to read [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599685/315935) where I describe how one can modify the code of jqGrid so that the total width of the grid would be adjusted after the user resize the column. I am not sure that you want exactly the behavior. I personally use this approach.