# Bootstrap: What to do when a very wide table won't fit within the grid

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that is part of a bootstrap div container. This jqGrid has variable width: the user can select up to twenty columns, and when he or she selects all twenty, it stands no chance of fitting within the bootstrap container. Is there a way to escape the bootstrap grid system when your HTML table is destined to be within a `<div class="container">`?

To clarify, I want the page to have a horizontal scrollbar without cutting off any content width-wise.

Answer (score 1):

An example of the code which you use could be helpful. Please take in consideration that not all who use jqGrid use bootstrap too. Because there are no code example currently and because I don't know bootstrap I try to guess.

I would recommend you to use `shrinkToFit: false` option. If you use the option you can consider don't specify `width` option for the grid. Instead of that you should specify `width` for every column as integer. In the case the grid will be displayed without horizontal scroll-bars, but the horizontal bars of the page can be used for scrolling. Probably other trick from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599685/315935) with resizing of grid after resizing of column could be also helpful in your case. Alternatively you can do specify the `width` option for the grid. All columns will be still displayed without any shrinking, but the horizontal scroll bars on the grid will be created.