# Unsortable headers get ui-jqgrid-sortable css class, how to change it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

```
colModel :[ 
    {name:'action', index:'action', width:220,
     sortable:false, formatter:valueToActionFormatter}
]
```

when I specifies the `sortable` option `false`, the headers still get `ui-jqgrid-sortable` css class. Google said `setColProp` can solve this issue. But how to do it? Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. It's not nice, that `ui-jqgrid-sortable` define `cursor:pointer` instead of `cursor:default`. You are not the first person which think so. You will find the workaround in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridSortableCursor.htm) which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639761/change-cursor-style-depending-on-sort-or-not/5640442#5640442).

**UPDATED**: The problem with the cursor on non-sortable columns is not exist more in [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).