# Attach method to all jqgrid instances?

Tags: jqgrid, jquery

I want to remove the pointer cursor from all non-sortable column headers in all of my jqGrids as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639761/change-cursor-style-depending-on-sort-or-not/5640442#5640442).  I currently do so for some of them in the `gridComplete` event.

Is there a way to set a default event, or grab all of the jqGrids on a page, and append that function the `gridComplete` event?  I could not find anything in the [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't change the value of `sortable` property of the columns *dynamically* you don't need to do this on every grid refreshing. The columns will be created once at the creating of jqGrid. So you can just place [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640442/315935) which fixes the cursor on non-sortable columns *after* the grid definition. So you don't need to use `gridComplete` or any other callback.

By the way I use the word "callback" instead of "event" used in jqGrid documentation because you can define really one callback per grid. So you can't easy define somewhere in common place `gridComplete` with *common* actions and use another `gridComplete` in the grid definition. So if you define `gridComplete` as default option `$.jgrid.defaults` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678731/315935)) it will default till you not *overwrite* it in the definition of some jqGrid. To fix the problem I posted detailed [suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/usage-of-jquery-events-in-jqgrid-together-with-callback-functions-used-currently/#p25559) how to extend functionality of jqGrid to support real events. Later I posted pull request with the changes. After long discussion the functionality is included in [the code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) of jqGrid. So the next version jqGrid (which should be published in a short time) will do have support events additionally to callbacks.