# jqGrid column header display slows down when scrolling horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using `jqGrid` with a horizontal scrollbar, but when I use the horizontal scrollbar the column header does not move together with the columns. Once I stop scrolling the grid comes back to normal. See the attached picture:
[image]

This is happening in FF (4.0.1) but not in IE8.

Here are the grid options I use:

```
width:'800',
shrinkToFit:false,
height: 500,
pager: '#pagerDiv',
gridview: true,
rowNum: 50,
rowTotal: 500,
sortorder: 'desc',
cellEdit: true,
cellsubmit: 'remote',
cellurl: 'MyURL',
beforeSaveCell: 
function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    return parse(value);
},
viewrecords: true,
loadComplete: loadCompleteHandler,
ignoreCase: true

....

jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
                            stringResult: true,
                            searchOnEnter: false });
    });
```

I have `jqGrid` version 3.8.2, `jQuery` 1.4.4 (full).
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's not a bug in jqGrid. What you describes looks like the difference how [jQuery.scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) are implemented in different web browsers. I'll try to explain why I think so.

To understand where are the problem you should know that **the column headers are not a part of the same HTML table**. At the creation time the `<th>` elements which builds column headers are really in the `<table>`, but then there are moved in another div. So one have always so named hDiv (header div) and bDiv (body div). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462071/jqgrid-get-th-and-thead-using-jquery/3463002#3463002) for details. Additionally the DOM element of table receive an expander (additional property) `grid` which save different additional information like `grid.hDiv` - the DOM element of the hDiv (header div) and `grid.bDiv` - the DOM element of the bDiv (body div).

Now about the scrolling. Because column headers are in another div the scrolling works asynchronous. To make it synchronized jqGrid register [jQuery.scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event handler for the `<table>` element (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.base.js#L2311)) and inside of the corresponding event handler [scrollGrid](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.base.js#L818) execute the following code:

```
grid.hDiv.scrollLeft = grid.bDiv.scrollLeft;
```

(see the line [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.base.js#L828)). So on every scrolling event on the table the scroll position will be synchronized.

The effect which you describe seem for me that FF (4.0.1) fire the `scroll` event only after you drop the scroll box.