# How can I set a Table ID on the table generated by JQGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I can't seem to find anything in the JQGrid documentation, but I want to select the table generated by JQGrid and want to set a unique ID on the generated table, is this easily done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a misunderstanding. To use jqGrid you should define at least the HTML fragment like

```
<table id="list"></table>
```

and use `$('#list').jqGrid({/*parameters*/})` to *convert* the existing table to the grid. The unique id must exist before you call jqGrid. The `id` will be used to construct ids on other elements of grid. (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462071/jqgrid-get-th-and-thead-using-jquery/3463002#3463002) for detailes). After creation of the grid you can't change the id of the table element. If it is *really required* to change the table id you have to destroy grid with respect of [GridDestroy](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) method, create new `<table>` element with the new `id` and then convert it to grid one more time.

Comment: You are absolutely right Oleg, funny enough I thought JQGrid had done some sort of destroy/create since I had wrapped in another table with no id.

Comment: @Mark Kadlec: All things are simple after we know the answer. You are welcome!