# JQgrid : disable table header mouse hover style

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to disable jqgrid table header hover style.
I tried answer from this solution [from another stackover flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213770/how-to-turn-off-column-highlighting-on-hover-for-a-jqgrid),

```
$($("#gridId")[0].grid.hDiv).find(".ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column")
.unbind("mouseenter")
.unbind("mouseleave");
```

it disable the header hover style but shows some error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'grid' of undefined(…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you executed the code **before** the grid is created. You should just move the code to the correct place. See https://jsfiddle.net/3304edu4/, which uses

```
$($("#grid")[0].grid.hDiv)
    .find("th.ui-th-column")
    .off("mouseenter mouseleave");
```

By the way you can move the code inside of `onInitGrid` callback, which will be called after the outer part of the grid (for example column headers) are created:

```
onInitGrid: function () {
    $(this.grid.hDiv)
        .find(".ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column")
        .off("mouseenter mouseleave");
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/3304edu4/1/