# Selecting the footerrow in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

jqGrid has an event `onCellSelect` Ref: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events  which you can use so you have event handling when a cell is selecting.  I am using a `footerrow` which contains totals and I need to have some event handling when cells in the footrow are selected.

Is there a corresponding event I can use?

Comment: Are you searching something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/14258048/666042 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in jqGrid footer select method.

I answer this question however in [Is a Footer row in a jqgrid selectable/clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245061/is-a-footer-row-in-a-jqgrid-selectable-clickable/14258048#14258048) which should put you on the right path.