# understanding jqGrid add method and Ajax request

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have an existing project that I need to maintain, but this is first time I meet the jqGrid...

Mainly, I have a `Product`, that can have multiple `Formule`s. Each `Formule` can contain multiple `Period`s. A `Period` is described by a `DepartureDate` and a `Price`.

This is the code that manages the Period's grid. Specially it adds the grid's navigator with the posibility of add `Period`s.

When adding a new row in the grid, the user fills-up a form containing 2 fiels:  the DepartureDate and a Price corresponding to the newly created Period.

```
    jQuery("#periode-grid").jqGrid(
        'setGridParam',
        {
            postData: {
                formuleId: rowid // <<< !!!
            },
            datatype: "json"
        })
        .navGrid("#periode-pager",
            {
                "edit": false, "add": true, "del": false,
                "search": true, "addtext": "@Resources.Main.Grid_Add"
            },
            {},
            {
                "url": '@Url.Action("AddAjaxPeriod",
                    new { elementId = @ViewData["ProductId"] })', // <<< !!!
                "closeOnEscape": true, "closeAfterAdd": true,
                "reloadAfterSubmit": true, "width": 500,
                "beforeSubmit": BeforeFormuleSubmit
            });
```

And this is my `AddAjaxPeriod` signature, containing 4 parameters, including the date and price:

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxRequestOnly]
[Transaction]
public JsonResult AddAjaxPeriod(Guid elementId, Guid formuleId, 
                                DateTime departureDate, double price)
{ ... }
```

Now everything works fine untill I open the form to add the price and date, fill-in the requested date and price, and click Validate.

I obtain an Error saying that `AddAjaxPeriod` requests `departureDate` non-optional parameter and is not filled-in... I could agree, I fill-in the `elementId` via the anonymous method, the `formuleId` is set in the `postData`, but the `departureData` and `price` are in the form the the user tries to add. Is there a way to get the values of that "add form" (date and price) and pass them into the `AddAjaxPeriod` method?

EDIT:

After the Oleg remarks, I found the grid initialization (in occurence in an parent partial view). This is the code:

```
jQuery("#periode-grid").jqGrid({
    "url": '@Url.Action("PeriodePagedList", new { elementId = ViewData["ProductId"] })',
    "datatype": 'local',
    "mtype": 'POST',
    "width": 400,
    "height": 100,
    "colNames": [
        "@Resources.Catalog_Products.FormulePeriode_DepartureDate",
        "@Resources.Catalog_Products.FormulePeriode_Price",
        "" // Actions
    ],
    "colModel": [
        { "name": 'DepartureDate', "index": 'DepartureDate', "editable": true, "align": 'center', "width": 100, "sorttype": 'date', "datefmt": 'dd/mm/yyyy', "editoptions": { "dataInit": function (element) { jQuery(element).datepicker({ "dateFormat": 'dd/mm/yy', "minDate": 0, "showAnim": '' }) } }, "editrules": { "required": true, "date": true } },
        { "name": 'Price', "index": 'Price', "editable": true, "align": 'center', "editrules": { "required": true }, "width": 100, "formatter": currencyFormatter, "unformat": unformatCurrency },
        { "name": 'Actions', "index": 'Actions', "width": 50, "align": 'center', "search": false, "sortable": false }
    ],
    "sortname": 'DepartureDate',
    "rowNum": 100,
    "loadComplete": OnLoadPeriodeComplete,
    "pager": jQuery('#periode-pager'),
    "pginput": false,
    "pgbuttons": false,
    "viewrecords": false,
    "imgpath": '@Url.Content("~/Content/jqueryui/images")',
    "caption": "@Resources.Catalog_Products.FormulePeriode_GridTitle",
    "shrinkToFit": true,
    "hidegrid": false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand all your problems. You don't posted enough details in the text of your question, so I have to guess a little.

First of all one use `setGridParam` method typically if one need to change **multiple times** some parameter of jqGrid, *after the grid is created*. On the other side it's important to understand that one can create the grid (with `jQuery("#periode-grid").jqGrid({...});`) or add the navigator (with `jQuery("#periode-grid").jqGrid("navGrid", ...);`) **only once**. During creating of the grid the initial empty `<table id="periode-grid">` will be converted in relatively complex structure of divs and tables (described shortly in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463002/315935) for example). So the second attempt to create already created grid will **do nothing**. In the same way the first call of `navGrid` will create navigator bar to the grid. The second attempt to call `navGrid` will just do nothing if the navigator bar already exist.

So I find very suspected combining calls of `setGridParam` and `navGrid` because one can be called only once and the another will be called typically multiple times.

If you need to send some additional parameter (like `formuleId`) to the server I would recommend you to use function form of properties of `postData`. So you can directly create jqGrid with the following option

```js
jQuery("#periode-grid").jqGrid({
    url: "someUrl",
    postData: {
        formuleId: function () {
            var someValue;
            // evaluate the CURRENT value of parameter which you need to sent
            // you can use someValue=$("#someControl").val(); for example
            ...
            return someValue;
        }
    }
```

In the way the value of `formuleId` used *during filling* of the grid will be always the current one.

During *editing* jqGrid send `id` parameter to the server. It's the rowid of editing row of the grid. So you should change the signatire of `AddAjaxPeriod` method to

```cs
public JsonResult AddAjaxPeriod(string id, Guid elementId, Guid formuleId, 
                                DateTime departureDate, double price)
```

If you prefer to rename `id` parameter you can use `prmNames` option of the grid. For example if the option `prmNames: { id: "myId" }` then you can use

```cs
public JsonResult AddAjaxPeriod(string myId, Guid elementId, Guid formuleId, 
                                DateTime departureDate, double price)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I edited my post adding some more detailed explanations. I need to recuperate the Date and Price from the form that permets to add a Period, to send them to the AddAjaxPeriod method.

Comment: @Serge: Sorry, but I still don't understand what you do. You added **description** of what you try to implement instead of JavaScript code which *really* works. You wrote about "DepartureDate" and "Price" columns of the grid but you defined `AddAjaxPeriod` method with **4 parameters** `elementId`, `formuleId`, `departureDate` and `price`. How other parameter will be sent? What are the names of columns in the grid? I recommend you to use at the beginning `string` type instead of `DateTime`, `double` and `Guid` and verify that the parameter will be non-empty in `AddAjaxPeriod`.

Comment: How other parameters will be sent? As we can see from the code, the `elementId` is sent directly via `new { elementId = @ViewData["ProductId"] }`, the `formuleId` is sent via `postData: { formuleId: rowid }`... So, I have just add in a way the date and price, both coming from the form that appears when I click the "Add"  button on the grid. This Add button will call the function `AddAjaxPeriod` with that 4 params.

Comment: @Serge: I don't understand your question. Moreover it's important to distinguish additional data which will be send during *filling of the grid* from the data sent *during editing of row of the grid*. The date and price which coming from **will be already sent** to the server, but the names of parameters depend on `colModel` of the grid which you don't posted. I suppose that the names of columns don't corresponds to the names of `AddAjaxPeriod` method. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE (press F12 to start) to trace HTTP traffic.

Comment: I found the "colModel", in a parent to that view. See my edits.

Comment: @Serge: If you use `name: 'DepartureDate'` and `name: 'Price'`. So you should use the same names in `AddAjaxPeriod` (in the same case). So I recommend you to try `public JsonResult AddAjaxPeriod(string id, string DepartureDate, string Price) {...}` and validate that `id`, `DepartureDate` and `Price` will be initialized.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem wasn't in the case, but in the type of parameters! Once set to string, the problem is gone!